# Numerical solution of the Laplace equation on circular domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

I was solving Laplace equation in MATLAB numerically. However I have problems when the domain is not rectangular.

The equation is as follows:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0
$$

domain is circular

$$
x^2 + y^2 < 16
$$

and boundary condition 
$$
u(x,y)= x^2y^2
$$

How should I start with solving this equation numerically ?

Comment: I have the same problem as you had. Could you help?. It's urgent. I need this program to solve some problems, but I'm bad using matlab.

Comment: @BlancaHernándezGalván Please don't post comments as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps begin by rewriting the problem in polar coordintates:
$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\theta^{2}}=0$$
$$r^2<16$$
$$\left. u(r,\theta)\right|_D=r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: But be careful around $r=0$ and that the function is periodic in $\theta$, $u(r,\theta)=u(r,\theta+2\pi)$.